# Admob banner integration in Cocos2d 2.0 / Admob banner in iphone games

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, admob

Does anybody know how to make work admob in cocos 2d v2, all the documentation is based in a view root controller and cocos2d 2 go just in another way.

The only documentation I found was this: [Working-with-admob-and-cocos2d](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/working-with-admob-and-cocos2d-v20.html)  but its a little poor for a newbie like me. If anyone can help me I appreciate too much!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my working admob cocos2d code: Copy createAdmobAds, showBannerView, hideBannerView and dismissAdView to your class.

Here is [Cocos2d 3.0 Admob Sample](https://app.box.com/s/7lsxp9u4lam2rym6i2x8) , for Cocos2d 2.0 check below

```
#import "GADBannerView.h"

typedef enum _bannerType
{
    kBanner_Portrait_Top,
    kBanner_Portrait_Bottom,
    kBanner_Landscape_Top,
    kBanner_Landscape_Bottom,
}CocosBannerType;

#define BANNER_TYPE  kBanner_Landscape_Bottom //change this on need basis

@interface MyMainMenu : CCLayer
{
    GADBannerView *mBannerView;
    CocosBannerType mBannerType;
    float on_x, on_y, off_x, off_y;
}

@implementation MyMainMenu


-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [self createAdmobAds];
}

-(void)onExit 
{
    [self dismissAdView];
    [super onExit];
}

-(void)createAdmobAds
 {
    mBannerType = BANNER_TYPE;

    AppController *app =  (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.

    if(mBannerType <= kBanner_Portrait_Bottom)
        mBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
    else
        mBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    mBannerView.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.

    mBannerView.rootViewController = app.navController;
    [app.navController.view addSubview:mBannerView];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [mBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;

    off_x = 0.0f;
    on_x = 0.0f;

    switch (mBannerType)
    {
        case kBanner_Portrait_Top:
        {
            off_y = -frame.size.height;
            on_y = 0.0f;
        }
            break;
        case kBanner_Portrait_Bottom:
        {
            off_y = s.height;
            on_y = s.height-frame.size.height;
        }
            break;
        case kBanner_Landscape_Top:
        {
            off_y = -frame.size.height;
            on_y = 0.0f;
        }
            break;
        case kBanner_Landscape_Bottom:
        {
            off_y = s.height;
            on_y = s.height-frame.size.height;
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    frame.origin.y = off_y;
    frame.origin.x = off_x;

    mBannerView.frame = frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    frame = mBannerView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = on_x;
    frame.origin.y = on_y;


    mBannerView.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


-(void)showBannerView
{
    if (mBannerView)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         {
             CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
             frame.origin.y = on_y;
             frame.origin.x = on_x;

             mBannerView.frame = frame;
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
         }];
    }

}


-(void)hideBannerView
 {
    if (mBannerView)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         {
             CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
             frame.origin.y = off_y;
             frame.origin.x = off_x;
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
         }];
    }

}

-(void)dismissAdView
 {
    if (mBannerView) 
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         { 
             CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
             frame.origin.y = off_y;
             frame.origin.x = off_x;
             mBannerView.frame = frame;
         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             [mBannerView setDelegate:nil];
             [mBannerView removeFromSuperview];
             mBannerView = nil;

         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats help me a lot! i will try to implement right now. Thnaks a lot!!

Comment: @Guru - In your code, you refer to AppController. What class is this? Is this your RootViewController? I am struggling to get this to work. Also, navController doesn't seem to be part of a UIViewController. Did you mean navigationController?

Comment: yes, in cocos2d AppController = AppDelegate. you can use UIViewController instead of navController.

Comment: After a closer read, I see that your question/answer is for cocos2D version 2. After some tweaking, I was able to get this working for version 1.1. However, even though I specified kBanner_Landscape_Top, the ad is appearing as if portrait_top. Additionally, the ad size is properly set to kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape, but since its displayed on the narrow side of the device, you cannot interact with it. If I change the ad size to kGADAdSizeBanner, then I can interact with the ad. However, if I open the ad and then close it, my cocos2d view switches to portrait. Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess its problem with CGSize s, print value of s. In cocos2d 1.0 just using view controller works.

Comment: @Guru - not sure what you mean about "just using view controller works". The value of s = (width=1024, height=768) for iPad. frame has an initialized origin of 0,0 and size of width=1024, height=90). With landscape top, the switch statement assigns off_y=-90.0 and on_y=0.0. I posted the modified code in a separate problem at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083777/admob-banner-not-displaying-landscape-in-cocos2d-version-1-1