# How to implement admob to cocoa2d on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode5, admob, chartboost

I am trying to add admob to cocoa2d project , but I didn't find any easy tutorial.
I just found the regular tutorial but its not helping me.

Because on the regular project there is ViewDidLoad and in the cocoa2d there isn't.

How I suppose to add admob to cocoa project?
Also can anyone guide me step by step what I need to do?

P.S: chartboost and revmob are easy on the appdelegate.

Thank you

We did all this methods but its not working:

[Admob banner integration in Cocos2d 2.0 / Admob banner in iphone games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278166/admob-banner-integration-in-cocos2d-2-0-admob-banner-in-iphone-games)

Comment: Good to see that you looked for other solutions before asking. Can you be more specific than "it's not working", though? Guru claims to have working code posted in the question you linked to; what kind of errors are you seeing when using it? Or are you unable to adapt that code to your project?

Comment: I search more then 5 solutions but nothing is not working,
i think i dont know how to add the admob to cocoa project.

on regular project there is ViewDidLoad and its easier and working.
i dont think its suppose to be so hard to add this.
i will glad if you can help me with this admob on cocoa.

Comment: i added all his code  that he added to the post to my project and i modified the code but its not working .
my main prob is instead the ViewDidLoad on regular proejct what i need  add to cocoa project that it will work.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this

Comment: I don't think you're going to get anything more detailed that Guru's answer to the other question unless you can narrow the problem down further than "it doesn't work".